# How to read TXT fiels from multiple cloud storage buckets in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, spark-streaming, hadoop-streaming

I want to list all the buckets from cloud storage which matches `gs://bucketname*`. I have tried using gsutil which is working but the same is not working from spark read or readstream.

gs://bucket1
gs://bucket2
gs://bucketN

working: `gsutil ls gs://bucket*/mydir/abcd*.txt`

not working: `sc.textFile("gs://bucket*/mydir/abcd*.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

gsutil implements wildcarding by performing bucket listing and object listing (with optional prefix) queries at the server and then filtering the results per the wildcard client-side. Since spark doesn't support that same functionality, you will have to list the buckets and objects and do the filtering yourself.